# Change Cell Colour Based On Class

Tags: javascript, class, cells

When I click on a cell with a specific class, I want other cells with the same class assigned to it to change to a certain colour and when I click on a different cell, I want it to have the same effect, but change the previous cells back to their default styles. From what I could gather from searching the interwebs, I would need to use Javascript, but my Javascript knowledge is seriously lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your question, I think you may have different cells with different classes that need to change.

I think something like this may work - where all elements to be clicked are divs contained in a wrapper with an id "clickable-cells". Divs that should play together should all have the same classes. Also, this is using jQuery.

```
$('#clickable-cells').children('div').click(function(){
    $('#clickable-cells').children('div').removeClass('inactive'); // Remove inactive class from all groups and elements
    targetClass = $(this).attr('class'); // Get the group class
    $('#clickable-cells div[class="'+targetClass+'"]').not(this).addClass('inactive'); // Make elements in this group inactive (use this class to change color)

});
```

Note the use of `[class="'+targetClass+'"]` instead of using `.` selector in case clickable elements have multiple classes.

Comment: Just a litte more info, I'm using a table and almost each cell has text in it. So when I click on say the first one, I want cells in the other columns, but not necessarily in the same row, to highlight. So just to make sure, should I add the divs around the text or the table elements and then add a main div around the whole table?

Comment: Just give the table an id of "clickable-cells" then change the target from 'div' to 'td' all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can implement this in the next way :

```
$('.cell').on('click', function(e){
    $(.selected).removeClass('selected'); // remove class from previously clicked cell
    $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

Where `.selected` is the class with the specific styles for the clicked cell or div or any element you want. `.cell` is the common class for each cell